# Group by wc results

Tags: linux, unix, aggregate

I have a directory that has about 100 files and sub directories
I want to find how many lines contain the string 'string' in EACH of the files in the current directory

I have tried 
`find . -name '*.h' -exec grep -i 'string'  {} +| wc -l`

But it shows me in total, does not give me the count by file.
I would like an equivalent of GROUP BY here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe wc -l *

Or for loop on find result with a wc inside

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
$ find . -name '*.h' -exec sh -c "echo {}; grep -i 'string' {} | wc -l" \;
```

or:

```
$ find . -name '*.h' -print -exec sh -c "grep -i 'string' {} | wc -l" \;
```

Example output:

```
./1.h
2
./10.h
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
grep -rc "string" base_directory
```

This should give count in each file in each directory within the base directory

Comment: we agree it gives me the number of lines by file??

Comment: Yes. If does. I tried with having the string twice in one line but still gave the number of lines